# how to write natural deduction proofs at mse

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm trying to write a question about natural dedcution, but I'm not sure what the best/easiest way is to write something similar to this at MSE:

[image]

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439291/prove-that-vdash-p-lor-lnot-p-is-true-using-natural-deduction/439627#439627) post, I tried this:

> 1. - $\lnot (p \lor \lnot p) \quad \quad \quad (H)$
> 2. - - $p \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (H)$
> 3. - - $p \lor \lnot p \quad \quad \; \;(\lor \text{I} 2)$
> 4. - - $ \bot \quad \quad \quad \quad \;\;(\lnot \text{E}1,3)$
> 5. - $\lnot p \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \; (\lnot \text{I}2 - 4)$
> 6. - $p \lor \lnot p \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\,(\lor \text{I}5)$
> 7. - $\bot \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,(\lnot \text{E}1,6)$
> 8. $p \lor \lnot p \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,\;\;\;(\bot \text{E}1-7)$

I think that this solution is not that bad, but using all those `\;` to align thinks is a little tedious. Does somebody has another/better solution to write natural deduction proofs at MSE ?

Answer (score 2):

I just do it all in ascii

(every line starts with 4 spaces)

```
1 |         ExVyRxy  Premisse 
2 | |____a           Variable
3 | | |__b  VyRby    Assumption
4 | | |     Rba      3 V-Elim
5 | | |     ExRxa    4 E-Intro 
. | | <--------------
6 | |       ExRxa    1, 3-5 E-Elim
. | <----------------   
7 |         VyExRxy  2-6 V- Intro
```

okay,  it uses some wrong symbols but most logicians can follow it

Comment: You can copy-and-paste these: ∀ ∃. I got them in turn by copying-and-pasting from rendered MathJax output ($\forall, \exists$).

Comment: the problem then is that you lose bits of the layout (nice collums and so and i like my collums